# DFS Recursion Space Usage PHP

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, memory-management, depth-first-search

Since arrays are not treated as objects in php, I have to manually reference them in order to recursively fill an array or constantly copy the new created/filled arrays from recursive calls.

"**return**" myRecursiveFunc() is not an option because that would end the function at the wrong time.

**One way: Referencing**

```
public function depthFirstSearchInOrder()
{
   $list = []; //otherwise php screams that only variables can be referenced (inside traverseInOrder) 
   //Otherwise I would have passed an empty [] as second parameter
   return traverseInOrder($this->root, $list);
}

function traverseInOrder($node, &$list)
{
   if ($node->left) {
      traverseInOrder($node->left, $list);
   }

   $list[] = $node->value;

   if ($node->right) {
      traverseInOrder($node->right, $list);
   }

   return $list;
}
```

**Second way: Creating/Copying arrays**

```
public function depthFirstSearchInOrder()
{
   return traverseInOrder($this->root);
}

function traverseInOrder($node, $list = [])
{
   if ($node->left) {
      $list = traverseInOrder($node->left, $list);
   }

   $list[] = $node->value;

   if ($node->right) {
      $list = traverseInOrder($node->right, $list);
   }
   return $list;
}
```

Doesn't the second way eat up way more space?
I'm creating new Arrays for each recursive call which I'm then copying again in $list.

Or am I just confused at the moment?

If I was to traverse this tree

```
//            9,
//       4,       20       
//    1,    6,  15   170
```

Using the second way

1. I would start with 9
2. Go left and call recursive (because of 4)
3. Go left and call recursive (because of 1)
4. I fill my empty array with 1 and return the array [1]
5. I'm back to value 4 where I now assign to $list = [1] (which now is a copy of [1] NOT a reference, right? So the array [1] still exists afterwards somewhere?
6. I push 4 in the array [1,4] and go right (because of 6)
7. I push 6 to the array [1,4,6] and return this array [1,4,6]
8. I'm back to value 4 where I now assign to $list = [1,4,6] (which now is a copy of [1,4,6] NOT a reference, right? So the array [1,4,6] still exists afterwards somewhere?

And so on and so forth...

**Back to my question:**

Isn't the second way more space hungry? Or am I just confused at the moment?